# How do I debug failing git push to flynn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flynn

I am trying to push a Ruby on Rails projekt to my Flynn remote. I am getting this error:

```
-----> Discovering process types
remote: -e:1:in `<main>': undefined method `keys' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
remote: ERROR: Build failed: exec: job exited with status 1
```

I have no 'keys' in any ruby file, and I am not even sure if that is what is meant with this error. Is there any logs with further information about the error? The project is working fine locally using Foreman, and an older version is also working fine at Flynn.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a configuration error and you will need to make sure your environment variables that you've set locally are available in your Flynn environment,

You can set your [environment variables on Flynn](https://flynn.io/docs/cli#env) with the CLI.